# What methods did the Old Babylonian society use for solving equations?

Tags: mathematics, ancient-babylon

According to the Wikipedia article on the Abacus, Ettore Carruccio stated in *Mathematics and Logic In History and In Contemporary Thought* that the Old Babylonians:

> may have used the abacus for the operations of addition and subtraction; however, this primitive device proved difficult to use for more complex calculations

<sub>translated by Isabel Quigly</sub>

The Old Babylonians, however, performed more complex mathematics than basic arithmetic. In the well referenced Wikipedia article on Babylonian mathematics it is stated that there is evidence they solved equations algebraically. Analysis of the Plimpton 322 tablet even seems to indicate they calculated a list of Pythagorean triples "too many and too large to have been obtained by brute force".

What methods then did the Old Babylonians use for solving equations? Were other devices aside from the abacus employed, or were these mostly manual methods on tablets? How did their manual methods differ from those we use today?

I'm not sure how much information we have on their mathematics. If there is a lot available, then this may be a little broad--in that case a summary of the state of research with links to good starting places to read about the research would make a useful answer.

**Referenced Wikipedia articles:**

- [Abacus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abacus)
- [Babylonian mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_mathematics)

---

*Note:* I have discovered papers such as [this](http://rudar.ruc.dk/handle/1800/24432), but I am unable to ascertain whether the paper is reputable (I'm unfamiliar with the scholars in this field) or whether it contains much in the way of an answer to my question. It would be nice to know that before purchasing access to a paper at random. In this case, the paper seems to be freely accessible and at a glance appears scholarly, yet I still cannot verify if it represents the current state of research.

Comment: This might be better on the math & science history forum.

Comment: Also, you are asking a lot of different questions here.

Comment: @TylerDurden There is truly one question. The rest is peripheral. The question is what methods they used for equation solving (whether device-assisted or manual).

Comment: @called2voyage Both articles have decent lists of literature in their footnotes. Have you had a look whether you can hunt any of them down?

Comment: @Marakai The items in the abacus references were either general overview or particular to the abacus. I'm reviewing the Babylonian mathematics references now to get you a more detailed reply regarding those.

Comment: @Marakai H. Lewy's 'Studies' are dated, and they are available on JSTOR where I would need to purchase access--a bit of an investment for what might not answer my question or might not be current.
S. Langdon's 'Assyriological notes' is also dated and I could not find it.
E. Robson's 'Guaranteed genuine originals' is more current, but I couldn't find it.
Asger Aaboe's *The culture of Babylonia* is an overview, no specifics.

Comment: @Marakai Otto Neugebauer's *The Exact Sciences in Antiquity* is also an overview. The rest was either in another language or not directly relevant.

Comment: @called2voyage Dang. That's WIkipedia for you. :(

Comment: @Marakai It's really a good amount of information for an encyclopedia. It just doesn't answer my particular question.

Comment: @called2voyage I've just looked for some German resources - they have a long history of Mesopotamian research going back a couple of centuries. There's a number of research papers on Babylonian mathematics within the last 10-20 years. How's your German? ;) Interesting paper: [Babylonische Mathematik](http://fsmat.at/~cerath/download/babylon.pdf), pages 10ff

Comment: @Marakai I couldn't remember how to spell "Sprechen sie Deustch" without looking it up, if that tells you anything.

Comment: Algebra typically means handling equations symbolically. why would they need more than writing material, and a good understanding of algebra?

Comment: @mart "Handling symbolically" can mean a lot of things. They certainly didn't represent it as x + y = z.

Answer (score 2):

You can see some general survey, like: Victor Katz, [A History of Mathematics: An Introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=h50fAQAAIAAJ) (3rd edition, 2008), **Ch.1.2 MESOPOTAMIA**, page 10-on.

There are references to "modern classics":

- Otto Neugebauer, [The Exact Sciences in Antiquity](https://books.google.it/books?id=JVhTtVA2zr8C&pg=PA29) (2nd ed, 1957), **Ch.2 Babylonian mathematics**
- B.L. Van der Waerden, [Science Awakening I](https://books.google.it/books?id=HK3vCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA62) (or.ed, 1954), **Ch.3 Babylonian mathematics**.

More recent and "technical":

- Jens Høyrup, [Lengths, Widths, Surfaces: A Portrait of Old Babylonian Algebra and Its Kin](https://books.google.it/books?id=GavTBwAAQBAJ&pg=PP4) (2002),
- Eleanor Robson, [Mesopotamian Mathematics, 2100–1600 BC: Technical Constants in Bureaucracy and Education](https://books.google.it/books?id=5gdVQRDYjYsC&printsec=frontcover) (1999).

Comment: The validation of Høyrup, at least, is helpful. Thanks! I'll need some time to analyze the rest to see if it answers my question.